# Javascript function full path

Tags: javascript

For example with explorer debug tools I've stopped inside some function using breakpoint ('DevTools' for example in Chrome).

Is it possible to know full path from that function context till Global context (`window` object)?

Like:

```
window.***.***.***.***.CustomFunction()
```

Is it possible?

Comment: In general, **no**. The function may not be associated as a direct or indirect property value of a `window` property.

Comment: You could do a deep lookup to find `CustomFunction()`'s `this` in a `window`...

Comment: What would you do with this information if you had it?

Comment: @EdinM Deep lookup is very hard on bigger JavaScript projects.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Well for curiosity and working with new JavaScript frameworks it might help to understand them better.

Comment: The Call Stack panel shows the path it took to get to your function call, which would likely be more informative of how a JS framework does its thing.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan true. In addition, it shows scope, which is another thing even more useful than "how do I call this directly". These two sources of information should be immensely more useful than just looking up where an object exists (if it can be reached directly, at all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to know full path from that function context till Global context (window object)?

If the function execution has not started from the `window` context (e.g. a function invoked from inside a closure), then no, the full path of its context will never reach the `window`.

As others have pointed out in the comments, your best bet is to use the `Call Stack` panel in conjunction with the `Scope` panel, in the `Sources` section of your dev tools.

You will get, literally, every bit of information you may ever want about a specific step in the callstack; how it came to be invoked, all the way to the very first trigger, and you can check all its scopes and what variables and functions it uses from each scope.

[image: Call stack]

You can even trace the stack from asynchronous calls, by enabling the `async` option. It's pretty great.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get the information you want, if not in that exact format, using [stacktrace.js](https://github.com/stacktracejs/stacktrace.js). Here is a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/esbsd1zd/1/), with code below. You'll need to open the console to see the output. (You can ignore the XMLHttpRequest error you will see on jsfiddle, the example still works there. If anyone knows how to fix that, please let me know).

```
var callback = function(stackframes) {
    var stringifiedStack = stackframes.map(function(sf) {
        return sf.toString();
    }).join('\n');
    console.log(stringifiedStack);
};

var foo = function () {
  var bar = function barFunction (fn) {
    console.log('I am bar');
    fn.call();
  };

  return {
    bar: bar 
  };
};

var baz = function bazFunction () {
  console.log('I am baz');
  StackTrace.get().then(callback);
};

var test = foo();
test.bar(baz);
```